# Display data from the database side by side

Tags: php, mysql

I get data from the database by 4 forms (wkNumer1, wkNumer2, wkNumer3 and wkNumer4).
I display data using a loop foreach. The data from the first form are displayed first, then the data from the second form, etc.

```
Loop 1
  $countWithoutE 
  $countE
  ect

Loop 2
  $countWithoutE 
  $countE
  ect
```

I would like to be able to display the data side by side.

```
$countWithoutE(from loop1) , $countWithoutE (from loop 2) ect
$countE (from loop2), $countE (from loop 2) ect
```

My code:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['show_diagram'])) {
    
    $goodname = $_POST['htDriver'];
    
    //Add the numbers to an array which we can iterate
    $wkNumbers =[
      $_POST['wkNumer1'],
      $_POST['wkNumer2'],
      $_POST['wkNumer3'],
      $_POST['wkNumer4'],
    ];
    //$wkNumer = $_POST['wkNumer1'];
   
      // Table with data
      $sql = "SELECT WorkingDay, OrderNo, NameFinish, Type  FROM `status` where WEEK(WorkingDay) = :wknumer AND NameFinish = :nameFinish"; // SQL with parameters
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 

      echo $goodname . '<br />';
      foreach ($wkNumbers as $wkNumer) {
        $stmt->bindParam("wknumer", $wkNumer);
        $stmt->bindParam("nameFinish", $goodname);
        $stmt->execute();
      
        $OCSdatas = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        $countWithoutE = 0;
        $countE = 0;
        foreach ($OCSdatas as $data) {
        
          if ($data['Type'] != 'E') {
            $countWithoutE = $countWithoutE + 1 ;
          }

          if ($data['Type'] == 'E') {
            $countE = $countE + 1 ;
          }

          //echo $data['OrderNo'] . $data['Type'] .  '<br>';
        }
        
        echo $wkNumer . '<br />';
        echo $countWithoutE . '<br>';
        echo $countE . '<br>';
        $countE = $countE/2;
        $countTotal = $countWithoutE + $countE;
        echo $countTotal/5  . '<br>';
        echo $count/5 . '<br>'
        
  }
}
  

?>
```

Comment: Could you just do the math in the SQL for each week? I guess that wouldn't really help with the question. You need to store the data, then output later, not in the same loop. You need all 4 iterations to be complete

Comment: what do you think is the best method to store data in this case?

Comment: Well you could restructure DB or use a `union` and select all without `e` then all with e. For answer about restructuring would need to know a lot more about db.